# Nodejs Openlayers 3 map server

Tags: node.js, openlayers-3

How would I go about to create a NodeJS / Openlayers 3 server side app that returns the complete image to the client?

For example the client would pass some parameters (extent, layers to be drawn and image size) to the server side NodeJS Openlayers 3 app.  Openlayers will then render the map in NodeJS and pass the final JPG image (complete map extent) back to the client.

Where can I get an example of doing this as I am new to NodeJS / Openlayers 3?

Comment: How about the client? Is it a browser?

Comment: @JonatasWalker It is an API

Comment: Do you have a running ol3/node environment? If no, take a look at this [guide](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/4e7f5582345433923113a7992d00a200208efab4/doc/tutorials/browserify.md).

Answer (score 0):

Here recommend some projects.

https://github.com/ginkgoch/node-map-server This is a lightweight map server API project that you could help to serve as an xyz tile server. And it could also support various kinds of data source. It provides docker to deployment which is pretty convenient.

Except this, there are other server I used to research. Here is a list:

1. https://github.com/geo-data/node-mapserv
2. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node-tileserver
3. https://www.maptiler.com/open-source/